# Using Google Sheets to split data from a column into different sheets

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work at a private international school which wastes a ton of paper. My goal is to reduce that by using google sheets to collect students lunch data from teachers, rather than writing it on paper weekly, then having someone input it all manually, then make separate sheets for each student manually.

I want to make this more efficient by using google sheets.

My google sheet 1 has all the students' data for a whole month with all their names and data in what I expect is a normal format. How can I use the google sheets split function to read the column with their names in, and separate data with the same name into its separate sheet?

[Screenshot of preliminary data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYXHb.png)

The picture shows the student's name repeating which will happen 4 or 5 times, depending on the month. Rather than manually separating them, I imagine there is a script I can use on google sheets to automatically read each repeated name and separate it into its own sheets.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take this chance to read [ask] and [mcve].  This information will help you to get a better response to your questions.  You also might find it useful take our [tour].

Comment: You image is hard to read and with redactions I find it useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you provide in fact has some opportunities but, I generate a [data sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WxBD9mcz5sFUyEuzlMK_fcLlmV6IbVxnNsmzdRdoEHs/edit#gid=0) for you to verify, I believe it represents the data you have.

In regard to your problem you can use a wide range of solutions one common is the:

> Filter Formula

[Here is some information on how to use it.](https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-formulas/filter-formula-google-sheets/)

So finally here is a [proposed answer sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WxBD9mcz5sFUyEuzlMK_fcLlmV6IbVxnNsmzdRdoEHs/edit#gid=1606698884) with this formula so you can check the full configuration of the solution.

You can also just copy paste the data you have in to it, if it has the same structure and it will dynamically adapt to your information. You can also copy this spreadsheet to make it private to you on `File> Make a copy`.

Other formulas you can use is `QUERY` or `VLOOKUP`

If you need further assistance you can contact one of stack overflow members through Stack overflow or you can join a social group like [this facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/326517934424375/) where we attend this kind of questions.

Comment: This was great! Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the clear presentation so I know how to better present in the future. Cheers.